# Alt + Left and Alt + Right allows me to switch between autocompletes in Utop, but tab will go back to first selection

Tags: search, autocomplete, ocaml, utop

In OCaml's utop, I can use alt+left or alt+right to move through autocomplete sections, but when I click tab to autocomplete the first selection is used. What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can complete with the current selection with `alt+down`.

If you type in `#utop_bindings;;`, you can see all keybindings.

You may also customize your bindings by creating a `~/.lambda-term-inputrc`-file, for example:

```
[read-line]
tab: complete-bar
```

See: https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop#key-bindings